# How to select and add data in existing file using Node JS?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angularjs

Can some body please explain , I have a large data in my json file and i have to select at some point like `data === smp('Report')`.

```
smp( "Reports" ) {
            smp( "firewall_real_time" ) {
                smp( "Appearance Settings" ) {
                    int( "Alignlogo" ) = 1812531465
                    int( "Alignlogo2" ) = 980706917
                    str( "Alignment" ) = ""
                    int( "Diagram Background Color" ) = 16777215
                    smp( "Fonts" ) {
                        smp( "Copyright" ) {
                            int( "Size" ) = 10
                            int( "Width" ) = 300
                            int( "XAxis" ) = 500
                            int( "YAxis" ) = 50
                        }
                    }
// I have to add extra data here so please help me how to add in between { { } }.
                 }
              }
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy.  I don't know your json file structure, but if you simply:

```
var data = require('./report.json');
```

Then "data" is just a regular JS object with all the same structure as in the file.  So if it looks like

```
{ "reports" : [ { "firewall_status" : "on"}]}
```

Or something like that, then data could do :

```
console.log(data.reports[0].firewall_status);
```

and it would print "on".

likewise, you could do something like

```
data.reports.push({firewall_status : "off"});
```

or whatever else you'd do with a plain old JS object.

When you're done, you'll probably want to write the data back to disk, so you would do so by stringifying the object and writing it out w/ the fs module:

```
fs.writeFile('./report.json', JSON.stringify(data, null, 4), function(err) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log('JSON saved');
    }
});
```

Comment: The above code which i added ,I just copied few lines from 12790 KB.so if whole file data equal to data then i think i have to use if(data === (smp('Reports)') { } like that . but i am confusing there are multiple '{' and '}'.  if i want to add data between {,{,{ data.substring() },},}.

Comment: ? I don't understand your comment.  I understand your overall JSON file is more complex than you wrote out, but what I answered will still let you access and modify the information in it, you just might have to nest more deeply.  That said, if you're looking at a data structure that's 12 MB big, you might consider a database such as MongoDB rather than a single JSON file in any case.

Comment: Thanks, I am sorry that is not a json file. It's in Gcf format.

Comment: smp( 9 ) {
      int( "Active" ) = 1
      str( "Name" ) = "windows_monitoring"
      vec( "Params" ) {
       str( 0 ) = ".\\res\\Reports"
       str( 1 ) = "windows_monitoring"
      }
      int( "Type" ) = 9
     }
    }
    str( "Last Modification Date" ) = "2014/04/17 16:40:13"
    str( "ListPath" ) = "REAL-TIME"
    int( "StopOnFailure" ) = 1
   }
// As you see after the above code ''smp( "Reports" ) {'' starts.

Comment: ? your question explicitly states that you're working with a JSON file.